Where put the Solr DefaultWrapperModel configuration?
on this section https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/learning-to-rank.html#using-large-models, we are advised to use the DefaultWrapperModel to load large models. But it does not say in which file you have to put the following config:
{
  "store" : "largeModelsFeatureStore",
  "name" : "myWrapperModel",
  "class" : "org.apache.solr.ltr.model.DefaultWrapperModel",
  "params" : {
    "resource" : "myModel.json"
  }
}

What file should receive the above configuration? There is nothing inside the documentation informing that.

The configuration using the DefaultWrapperModel does not live inside any file. It has to be sent to the /solr/collection-name/schema/model-store URL. The large model is configured inside any file. Then the lightweight DefaultWrapperModel config is sent over HTTP.
